# Is it OK to discuss a student's work without them present?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, peer-review

At my university, PhD students need to give a presentation at the end of their first year. A panel of academics judge the work and then have a Q&A session with the student to assess their progress and aptitude. The panel has the power to delay progress if they have any concerns. It can be a stressful time for students.

There has been a suggestion from a colleague that we arrange a discussion after the presentation (during the Q&A time) so that junior students can learn what is required. However, I'm not sure that this is right because the student is not present - they're answering questions of the panel.

Though I do see value in the discussion, I think it might be best for all involved to be done as a separate, trial presentation. This way the PhD candidate can modify their presentation to make it better and the discussion can be had without the student being absent. However, this means two talks so it's more time for all involved and may add stress/confusion for the candidate.

I'd be happy to know how other universities do things and what you think.

Comment: I'm a little confused. What aspect do you intend to discuss? If it's the presentation, then perhaps it's better to just let other students watch (you don't want to be pointing out where one of their fellow students went wrong). If it's the Q&A, I don't see how having the discussion then helps, since they don't see that anyway.

Comment: @JessicaB: In PhD, having a discussion on this would certainly help. Every graduate student would want their presentation to have an impact. Analysis of a peer's  presentation would certainly help one's own in the future. But as Eddie stated, I do feel it would be better to have the scholar who has presented to be present in the discussion too.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac I still don't get what is to be discussed. If it really is a discussion of how well the student presented their work, then the idea should never have arisen. The only student faculty should discuss that with is the student themselves. To do otherwise is downright cruel. Students are free to discuss among themselves if they choose, but leading such a discussion is akin to taking the student's written work and pointing out the errors to their coursemates.

Comment: @JessicaB, a positive critic could help improve the art of the presentation itself. The comment is not about how bad you did your work or how inefficient the research was. Some examples that could be covered in the discussion may include the low of presentation, level of detail, amount of detail in each slide, sections, and so on.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac What aspect of that requires the discussion to be after a student has presented? If you're specifically refering to the student, you will only increase stress levels. If you are not, do it some other time, like after a research seminar. If you need specific examples, find a student who already did a good presentation and ask if you can show their slides to other students. Get students to set up a junior seminar where they can practice speaking to a friendly audience without faculty around. Don't critique a student's work to their peers.

Comment: @JessicaB: I do agree; this has to be done with the consent of the graduate student. The discussion would be healthier if the focus is on positive examples. This would also increase the morale of the student. Besides, did you say stress? If you couldn't handle a stress in a discussion with your peers, how could would you face the thesis committee during the dissertation defence?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac Not everyone gets stressed about the same things. Maybe you feel that way, but others can see it differently. Besides, saying 'it's ok if we make it more stressful now because there's something even worse down the line' is not very helpful. Particularly when the initial justification was to reduce stress!

Answer (score 4):

I think the basic rule is that you should not evaluate one student in the presence of others. The problem with carrying out a public evaluation "with the student's consent" is that that the student may feel pressured to give their consent.

On the other hand, if a student gives a talk in a friendly environment, then I believe it is appropriate to hold a public discussion about how the presentation could be improved. Care is needed, but I have found that it works. We usually start by asking the student what they would do differently next time.

Answer (score 2):

(Since it looks like I've understood the question, I'll turn the ideas in my comments into an answer.)

As I see it, the students are finding the situation stressful because they are required to do something they feel uncertain about, there is an obvious cost to failing, and they don't feel confident in their ability to meet the required standard.

The proposal is to use students' work, which they are already feeling worried about, for the benefit of others (not themselves). Having been on the receiving end of this themselves (except the first few), they should feel a bit more confident that they understand the requirements. On the other hand, now in addition to the academic assessment they are also to be assessed by their social group, either in their presence or otherwise (some will find one more stressful, others the other). Most PhD students can work out for themselves what aspects of a talk were worth copying, but explicitly pointing them out in a group setting is more judgemental, even if only positive things are directly said ('damning with faint praise'). They will have to spend several more years with these people, providing moral support to each other. The overall effect then is to slightly reduce the likelihood of failure, but significantly increase the cost.

I think the same benefit could easily be gained in a much better way. Choose a student who did a good job in their presentation, and ask whether they would be willing to do a repeat to help others. Some will be too shy, but it shouldn't be long before there is one who is willing. For a repeat performance, there is no academic cost attached. Messing up ultimately won't matter, so the student will feel more confident. They also have the additional confidence from being chosen as an example of a success. This time, they are essentially being honoured within the social grouping, rather than critiqued, so they are being rewarded rather than being put at risk of shame. By videoing the talk, you would only need to go through this once.

The main method I've known for students to become less stressed about having to give a presentation is for them to have opportunities to practice doing so where the potential cost is very low, the main example being in junior seminars (student-run seminars, preferably without faculty present), although reading groups are another avenue. In addition to direct practice, such activities build community within the group, which is likely to reduce the difficulty because students can find out what is required of them by discussing with their peers who have already been through the process. If you'd prefer to have more direct input, one option might be to have a graduate class whose explicit purpose is for everyone to get better at presenting, by having people give presentations that are then discussed (no grades though).